# Python - Cannot Send Email

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtplib

I am running Python 3.4.2, on Windows 7 Enterprise, 64 bit.

I have the below script (write_email.py) that receives an error when run:

```
# smtplib module send mail

import smtplib

TO = 'address@somedomain.com'
SUBJECT = 'TEST MAIL'
TEXT = 'Here is a message from python.'

# Gmail Sign In
gmail_sender = 'address@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = ''   #this is left blank on purpose

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-relay.gmail.com', 25)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO,
                'From: %s' % gmail_sender,
                'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,
                '', TEXT])

try:
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
print ('email sent')
except:
    print ('error sending mail')

server.quit()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "email_test.py", line 17, in <module>
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)
File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 652, in login
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (501, b'5.5.2 Cannot Decode response       13sm147030
88ith.4 - gsmtp')
```

I've done a lot of searching to resolve this, but so far no luck.

Comment: As is clear from the error, it is the authenticating part that causes your head ache. Perhaps it is just the password that is left blank on purpose that causes the authentication failure?

Comment: I got the same error and it was a blank password... Thanks @MA53QXR